# Spring boot microservice as Kafka consumer exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Im trying to integrate kafka on my spring boot project but I'm having an exception.

```
2021-07-13T13:22:13.12+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT {"@timestamp":"2021-07-13T13:22:13.129+08:00","@version":"1","message":"Located property sour
igService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource {name='configClient'}, MapPropertySource ]}","logger_name":"org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO"
   2021-07-13T13:22:13.14+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT {"@timestamp":"2021-07-13T13:22:13.148+08:00","@version":"1","message":"'cloud' property sour
ry.reconfiguration.CloudPropertySourceApplicationContextInitializer","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
   2021-07-13T13:22:13.14+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT {"@timestamp":"2021-07-13T13:22:13.149+08:00","@version":"1","message":"Reconfiguration enabl
onfiguration.CloudServiceReconfigurationApplicationContextInitializer","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
   2021-07-13T13:22:13.15+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT {"@timestamp":"2021-07-13T13:22:13.156+08:00","@version":"1","message":"Refreshing org.spring
ConfigApplicationContext@57e03347: startup date [Tue Jul 13 13:22:13 SGT 2021]; parent: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationCo
290dbf45","logger_name":"org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_va
   2021-07-13T13:22:13.19+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT {"@timestamp":"2021-07-13T13:22:13.193+08:00","@version":"1","message":"Skipping reconfigurat
igured","logger_name":"org.cloudfoundry.reconfiguration.CloudServiceReconfigurationBeanFactoryPostProcessor","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO",
   2021-07-13T13:22:13.21+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT {"@timestamp":"2021-07-13T13:22:13.215+08:00","@version":"1","message":"JSR-330 'javax.inject
 for autowiring","logger_name":"org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor","thread_name":"main","level":"
   2021-07-13T13:22:13.41+0800 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT {"@timestamp":"2021-07-13T13:22:13.410+08:00","@version":"1","message":"Exception encountered
ling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'binderHealthIndicator' def
m.binder.rabbit.config.RabbitServiceAutoConfiguration$RabbitHealthIndicatorConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'binder
ception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate' defined in org.spring
nfig.RabbitServiceAutoConfiguration$CloudProfile$CloudConnectors$UseCloudConnectors: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'rabbitTempl
rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory' defined in org.springframework.cl
erviceAutoConfiguration$CloudProfile$CloudConnectors$UseCloudConnectors: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.sp
ception: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'rabbitConnectionFactory' threw exc
ramework.cloud.CloudException: No unique service matching interface org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory found. Expected
amework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext","thread_name":"main","level":"WARN","level_value":30000}
```

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-service-registry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

This is my reference tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyaFygU9C2Q

Thank you!

Comment: I can see in logs, Spring is unable to inject rabbitTemplate , so please create a bean and annotate with @Bean

Comment: @karthikakinapelli I'm confused sorry but I'm not using rabbitmq. I'm using Kafka. Why is it looking for rabbitmq?

Answer (score 0):

Add `rabbitTemplate` related dependency and create `rabbitTemplate bean` in your configuration class then do the Autowireing.

If not using the remove rabbitTemplate related configuration from your code.

Comment: Hi, I'm very new to this. can you provide example? thank you!

Comment: Hey that video example the publishing event to cloud. You also doing the same thing or not if so add spring cloud dependency also.

Comment: If you try to learn Kafka with spring  boot then try to run the Kafka locally with some topics and do the producer and consumer things.

Comment: There are some good tutorial there for basic understanding.  https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-kafka/